# Best way to impletent Java multithreading to prevent transaction rollback

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8, transactions

I have an List which contains say 4 DTOs. I am performing some processes on each of the DTOs present in my list. If suppose for one the DTO, any exception comes then all the transactions are rolled back (even if the process is success for other 3 DTOs).

My code looks like this :

```
@Transactional
public void processEvent(List<MyObject> myList){
   myList.forEach(dto -> process(dto));
}

public void process(MyObject dto){
//some code which calls another class marked as @Transactional
// and save the data processed to database
}
```

I want to perform these processes for each DTO on a sepearte thread such that exception encountered in one thread does not rollbacks transaction for all the DTOs.
Also is there a way to process these DTOs one by one on different threads so that data consistency is maintained ?

Comment: What makes you think this code is multithreaded? There is nothing multi threaded about that code. If you want a new transaction per object, then do that, create a new transaction, that is what the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation level is for.

Comment: @M.Deinum I know my code is not multithreaded. I am confused what is the best practice to make my code multithreaded so that i get a new transaction per object (with data consistency maintained) ?

Comment: @YashAgarwal . . . you don't need to make your code multithreaded in order to get a new transaction. Just use the `propagation` attribute of the Spring `@Transactional` annotation as M. Deinum said. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html . . .

Comment: @MatheusCirillo Thanks for clarification. Earlier I was not sure about how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the transactional to the method called with the dto, plus I am not sure if it is needed a transaction for dto. This looks as a controller which should not have any transactional annotaions. In the service once you change the dto to entity and are ready to save it you may put the anotation. Furthermore if you are simply calling the repository's save method you do not need to be in transaction as save method has the annotation in the repository.

```
public void processEvent(List<MyObject> myList){
   myList.forEach(dto -> process(dto));
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void process(MyObject dto){
//some code which calls another class marked as @Transactional
// and save the data processed to database
}
```

And one last advice do not put @Transactional on classes, except if they have the readOnly parameter set to true. Then you can put @Transactional on the methods that perform any CRUD operations.